# Dealing with column conversions in Ruby ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, legacy-database

Dealing with a legacy database, I've come across a column in a SQL Server database where the date is stored as a decimal.  E.g. 2011-04-23 is stored as 20110423.0.

Is there a general ActiveRecord mechanism for dealing with "weird" column storage conventions?  Enum-like columns where they're actually stored as integers is another case that might also make use of the same mechanism, but I can't quite find what I'm looking for.

It seems like serialization gets me partly there:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  class DecimalDate
    def load(date)
      if date.is_a? Numeric
        y,m,d = /^(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/.match(date.to_s)[1..3].map(&:to_i)
        Date.civil(y,m,d)
      end
    end
    def dump(date)
      date ? date.strftime('%Y%m%d').to_i : 0
    end
  end
  serialize :weird_date, DecimalDate
end

rails c
> Thing.first.weird_date
=> Sun, 02 Jan 2011
```

But, the illusion is thin.  The column doesn't "know" that it's a date stored as a decimal.  E.g. comparisons fail:

```
rails c
> Thing.where('weird_date > ?', 1.week.ago)
...
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: ... Error converting data type varchar to numeric.:
```

Comment: Can you migrate data to a convention supported by Rails? Or are you forced to deal with it?

Comment: Can you hide all accesses to `weird_date` inside your Thing? That would at least localize the weirdness.

Comment: @basgys: unfortunately, forced to deal with it.

Comment: @muistooshort: That's probably possible.  It just seems like Rails would have some facility like what I'm after.  Every time I've dealt with a legacy database in Rails, I've come across something similar to this.  (The "enum as int" example I gave, and another SQL Server DB where booleans were proper "bit" columns.)

Comment: But the enum and boolean values are driver-level issues, not application-level issues. You could try to monkey patch the date-to-string mangler but that would probably cause more problems. I don't think anything outside the model should be calling `where` anyway (despite common practice) but I'm opinionated and cranky about proper layering :)

Comment: @muistooshort: yeah, that's how I solved the boolean-v.-bit(1) issue.  It was a SQL Server DB converted to MySQL, so I patched the Mysql2 connection adapter to use 'bit(1)' for :boolean, and "b'1'" and "b'0'" for QUOTED_TRUE and QUOTED_FALSE.  Probably going to stick with serialization if no one has other ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are forced to deal with legacy data I see two possibilities to manage it.

**1 From your database**

You can "convert" your data by making a view of your table which convert your (date) fields on the fly. Then you make a trigger (before insert/update) on this view which convert your data back to your old format. Finally you tell ActiveRecord to use your view instead of your table.

**2 From your application (Rails)**

Find a way to tell ActiveRecord to do the same job. Have you already tried to manage it with AR callbacks with **after_initialize** and **before_save**? More informations [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)